# aligning equation

Tags: equations, align

Regarding the enclosed MWE I would like to get the `\sum`s aligned. But using a second & in lines two and three leads of course to a problem with line one. How do I get the desired result? (Looking into Herbert's fine mathmode was to no avail.)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 S(f) & ={} \pi\left(S(f-f_0)+S(f+f_0)\right)\\
      & ={} \pi\tau\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\left(\dfrac{k}{\tau}-f_0\right)+\right.\\
      &                      \left.\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\left(\dfrac{k}{\tau}+f_0\right)\right)
\end{align*}
\end{docum
```

Comment: BTW: why `={}`?

Comment: I experienced that otherwise there is (sometimes?) a missing distance between the = and the following term. Maybe that it is not necessary anymore ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```
\phantom{= \pi\tau\left(\vphantom{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}}\right.}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
```

after the `&` like in

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 S(f) & = \pi\left(S(f-f_0)+S(f+f_0)\right)\\
      & = \pi\tau\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\left(\dfrac{k}{\tau}-f_0\right)+\right.\\
      & \phantom{= \pi\tau\left(\vphantom{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}}\right.}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
           \left.\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\left(\dfrac{k}{\tau}+f_0\right)\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\biggl` etc, it would be

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 S(f) & = \pi\left(S(f-f_0)+S(f+f_0)\right)\\
      & = \pi\tau\Biggl(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\biggl(\dfrac{k}{\tau}-f_0\biggr)+\\
      & \phantom{{}={}\pi\tau\Biggl(}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
           \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\biggl(\dfrac{k}{\tau}+f_0\biggr)\Biggr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And with `aligned` as suggested by dalief

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 S(f) & = \pi\left(S(f-f_0)+S(f+f_0)\right)\\
      & = \pi\tau\!
         \begin{aligned}[t]
         \Biggl(&\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\biggl(\dfrac{k}{\tau}-f_0\biggr)+\\
         & \sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k \delta\biggl(\dfrac{k}{\tau}+f_0\biggr)\Biggr)
         \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is better to use the last option.

Comment: Just as a comment to the OP: Or (since it is `align*`) use aligned to align the stuff inside the big ()'s. Also not always a good idea to use those broken `\left...\right.` ... `\left. ... \right)` constructions

Comment: @daleif It is a good idea. Thanks and added.

Comment: I don't think you need dual `\!`. I usually also include the starting `(` in `aligned` when I do this. Then I know the spacing inside the `()`'s will be ok and I only need the *traditional* `\!` in front.

Comment: @daleif That sounds good too. :)

Comment: My answer would have just the second option. `;-)` I agree with daleif that `\!\!` is not needed and, in this particular case, neither the single `\!` is, because of the protruding “k”.

Comment: @egreg Oh No!, I am caught between mathematicians ;-). Running away (for a class). Thanks and have nice time :)

Comment: Ok, that idea was in my mind, too, but I hoped for a more elegant solution (although I have no clue how it should look like). Many thanks to Harish and daleif!

Comment: I'd say that `Bigg`-sized parentheses are too big; I would recommend using `bigg`-sized ones.